# Intro_Slider Error Occured: Try Correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am following a tutorial on how to create an Intro Slider Screen in Flutter in Android Studio using the intro_slider package, and saw a source code online. However, when I try to execute them, it gives me many errors. Please help. The following are the errors that was shown:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'. 

      return FlatButton(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**ERROR UPDATE:**

[Unable to load asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Lz5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Will Working fine :**

**you just need to import package** *intro_slider: ^2.3.4*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/dot_animation_enum.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/slide_object.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class IntroSliderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroSliderPageState createState() => _IntroSliderPageState();
}

class _IntroSliderPageState extends State<IntroSliderPage> {
  List<Slide> slides = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Hello Food!",
        description:
            "The easiest way to order food from your favorite restaurant!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/hamburger.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Movie Tickets",
        description: "Book movie tickets for your family and friends!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/movie.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Great Discounts",
        description: "Best discounts on every single service we offer!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/discount.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "World Travel",
        description: "Book tickets of any transportation and travel the world!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/travel.png",
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> renderListCustomTabs() {
    List<Widget> tabs = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      Slide currentSlide = slides[i];
      tabs.add(
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 160, top: 60),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    currentSlide.pathImage.toString(),
                    matchTextDirection: true,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.title.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 30,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.description.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      height: 1.5,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntroSlider(
      backgroundColorAllSlides: Colors.green[700],
      renderSkipBtn: Text("Skip"),
      renderNextBtn: Text(
        "Next",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[700]),
      ),
      renderDoneBtn: Text(
        "Done",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[700]),
      ),
      colorDoneBtn: Colors.white,
      colorActiveDot: Colors.white,
      sizeDot: 8.0,
      typeDotAnimation: dotSliderAnimation.SIZE_TRANSITION,
      listCustomTabs: this.renderListCustomTabs(),
      scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      onDonePress: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the codes in intro_slider.dart with your code, however it says an error:

Comment: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.

Comment: Complete Source Code https://github.com/ChMobinansar/flutter_intro_slider

Comment: You work with null safety ?

Comment: what do you mean? anw, im tryng out the source code you have provided.

Comment: kindly mark as accepted answer @annyeongk

Comment: done. thanks. however, why it says unable to load asset?

Comment: image can't loaded i think so.

Comment: Why is text and image is not showing?

Comment: this is working fine for me

Comment: Really? Pls help I tried changing the text and image but not working. I'll update this post with how it looks like

Comment: ok don't worry i will check

Comment: ok please do tysm

Comment: @annyeongk check the latest Source it's work fine

Comment: i just need to paste that in my intro_slider.dart right?

Comment: yes of course check it